# Passar valor atribuído ao enum por parâmetro de método

Tags: java, tipagem, método, parâmetros, enums

Eu tenho um valor que armazena o status de um elemento. Por exemplo: 1 - a enviar 2 - Cancelada 3 - Erro.

O valor que será salvo no banco é o valor numérico. Tenho um método que seta o status, mas o parâmetro dele é do tipo numérico.

O fato é que eu não queria ter que passar o valor em si, mas queria passar utilizando `enum`.

```java
setStatus (Status.CANCELADA);

public enum Status {
     A_ENVIAR(1L), CANCELADA(2L), ERRO(3L);
    
     private Long numVal;
    
     Status(Long numVal) {
         this.numVal = numVal;
     }
    
     public Long getNumVal() {
         return numVal;
     }
}
```

Mas para pegar o valor numérico que cada `enum` representa, eu estou tendo que fazer `Status.CANCELADA.getNumVal()`.

Tem alguma forma de eu pegar o valor "2", sem precisar chamar o método `getNumVal()`? Eu quero o valor 2 chamando apenas `Status.CANCELADA`.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

galera!

Só faltou eu pensar um pouco, estava pensando em uma solução não necessária.

Defini na própria classe as constantes com seus respectivos valores de forma pública e estática.

```java
public static final int A_ENVIAR = 1;
```

Então eu só chamava

```java
setStatus(ClasseEmQuestao.A_ENVIAR);
```

Answer (score 4):

Por que não usa o método [`ordinal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()) que todo `enum` tem? Fica assim:

```
class Program {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Status status = Status.Cancelada;
        System.out.println(status.ordinal());
    }
}

enum Status {
    None, AEnviar, Cancelada, Erro;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ptzDUJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/cktrgdkf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/EnumOrdinal.java).

Eu dei uma melhorada nesse código e sem usar essa besteira que ensinaram de escrever tudo em Caps (dá para fazer do seu jeito também, mas é muito feio, precisa criar o construtor, aí tanto faz usar método pronto ou um próprio).

Comment: O `ordinal` é uma boa solução, mas e se ele precisar que cada valor do enum realmente tenha um _valor interno_ (não sei a terminologia disso no Java) pré-definido, seguindo critérios externos ao código? E em relação ao _caps_, concordo que seja feio, mas é a convenção que a própria Oracle [parece seguir](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), portanto não seria melhor o seguir?

Comment: Aí não funciona, mas a pergunta não fala sobre isso, ela mostra um padrão sequencial. Eu acho que coisa tão feia quanto essa não deveria seguir, não há ganho algum nisso.

Comment: @Maniero O que não tem ganho algum é essa [imposição da cultura do C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17965469/2241463) sobre a comunidade Javeira marginalizada :D Olha a treta rs. Para não prolongar a discussão vou só deixar o link dos argumentos que foram centralizados nessa pergunta do SOen tratando do assunto, quem quiser vote lá: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3069743/2241463

Comment: Não há ganho as pessoas fazerem coisas sem saber o motivo, inclusive os criadores do Java. Se usava CAPS em C porque era macro não porque era constante, alguém da Sun não entendeu isso e resolveu que aquilo era pra constante e decidiu que ia importar essa coisa feia pro Java. Por sorte as pessoas que cuidam do Java agora são bem melhores e não cometem esses erros mais, assim as pessoas podem começar evitar o erro inicial. O único argumento a favor disso é que "a Sun mandou a gente fazer isso".

Comment: @Maniero Falei mais em tom de brincadeira para deixar o link, não precisava dar essa invertida :D Mas [vou refletir](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9h6esFsqloA).

Answer (score 1):

Não tem como fazer isso. Até porque, se fosse possível, você poderia fazer algo como:

```
Status.CANCELADA == 2L; // ???
```

E isso deveria ser avaliado para o quê? `true`? `false`? Como o *runtime* seria capaz de distinguir quando deve retornar o `Long` (representação dos valores no exemplo) ou `Status` (o próprio tipo da enumeração em questão)?

A expressão anterior nem é executada – um erro é lançado por conta dos tipos incompatíveis:

```
Main.java:XX: error: bad operand types for binary operator '=='
    x == 1L;
      ^
  first type:  Status
  second type: long
```

Portanto, é ideal que se crie uma forma para expor o valor da propriedade. No caso, você já está fazendo isso pelo método `getNumVal`.

Comment: Só uma correção/esclarecimento, enums foram feitos para se comparar com enums, usando o `==`, pois são "singletons" por design. Então para o caso do AP estar querendo comparar num nível mais alto um status de um elemento com o valor `Status.CANCELADA` pode fazer `meuElemento.getStatus() == Status.CANCELADA` ou conforme o caso até criando uma API `meuElemento.isCancelada()` que verifica isso internamente, mas tem que providenciar a conversão do nível mais baixo trazido do banco (número, Long) para o nível mais alto que é a instância do enum, no DAO ou ORM que estiver usando, por exemplo.

Comment: Sim, @Piovezan, justamente por isso mencionei a parte do erro de _runtime_ ao tentar comparar o `Status` direto com o valor interno (`2L`, por exemplo). Realmente não faz sentido comparar um `enum` com algo que não seja elemento da própria enumeração.

Comment: Ah, acho que agora entendi o que o AP queria. Ele quer um `setStatus(enum)` de alto nível. Aí dentro da implementação desse `setStatus()` é que deveria invocar o `getNumVal()` (ou `ordinal()`) da instância de enum que foi fornecida.